# Is it possible to read values from database table like MySQL and update it dynamically in shiny app data table

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server, shinydashboard, shinyjs

Can we read the table from database like Mysql, which updates based on submit button and again have to read it and display it in shiny application without rerunning again?